# Logarithmic interpolation of Reynold numbers vs drag coefficient

Tags: matlab, interpolation, spline, logarithm, loglog

> The table shows the drag coefficient `cD` of a sphere as a function of
>   Reynolds number `Re`. Find `cD` at `Re = 5, 50, 500, 5000`. Hint: use
>   log–log scale.
>
> ```
> Re 0.2 2 20 200 2000 20000
> cD 103 13.9 2.72 0.800 0.401 0.433
> ```

I don't understand how to "use log-log scale" to solve this problem. I tried the below codes but I don't know whether it is correct or not. How can I use the log-log scale here?

you can find original of question below link

https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2Faef%2Faef9a122-1a83-423d-9258-66fac0cac8e4%2FphpCF4Vwd.png

```matlab
r = [0.2, 2, 20 ,200, 2000 ,20000];
c = [103, 13.9, 2.72 ,0.800 ,0.401 ,0.433];
rI = [5,50,500,5000];
cI = spline (r,c, rI);
```

Comment: i need to find polynominal that passes through all x-y point and plot it the polynomial curve.  after accomplishing this convert it back to x-y data and plot it on a log-log scale with "loglog" command. i have no idea how to create x-y data points without knowing of degree of the equalation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do for this question, is to **compute the logarithm** of your X and Y values and only then perform interpolation. If you look at the [drag coefficient of a sphere](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Drag_coefficient_of_a_sphere_as_a_function_of_Reynolds_number.png),

[image: Cd vs Re]

you'll see that this chart (and other similar charts) is *plotted* using logarithmic scales. Note that the red curve is quite smooth and well-behaved with the exception of the transition point around 3E5, where flow separation occurs.

To solve your assignment, you need to perform interpolation "using the red curve", that is, in a logarithmic domain. The reason for doing this is because the spans of the X and Y values are very large, and a polynomial or a spline over the original domain would not capture the behavior correctly. Practically -

```matlab
r = [0.2, 2, 20 ,200, 2000 ,20000];
c = [103, 13.9, 2.72 ,0.800 ,0.401 ,0.433];
rI = [5,50,500,5000];
cI = exp( spline( log(r), log(c), log(rI)) ); % interpolation is performed for log(y) vs log(x)
%{
cI =
    6.9390    1.5843    0.5636    0.3717
%}
```

The correctness of these results can be validated manually using the chart.

Comment: i want to proceed like this.   r = [0.2, 2, 20 ,200, 2000 ,20000];
c = [103, 13.9, 2.72 ,0.800 ,0.401 ,0.433];
x = log(r);
y = log(c);
plot(x,y);
fig = gcf;
axObjs = fig.Children;
dataObjs = axObjs.Children;
xx = dataObjs(1).XData;
yy = dataObjs(1).YData;
r2 = 10.^xx;
c2 = 10.^yy;
rI = [5,50,500,5000];
cI = spline (r2,c2, rI) what is wrong with the my syntax and alrgorithm

Comment: first of all i want to create polynomial figure from given values. then convert it to r-c data again. then spline it with created equation.

Comment: You don't need to change the data in any way in order to plot the figure. Just use `loglog` instead of `plot`.